# Error Converting Date from Character String

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a csv imported table, where I'm trying to convert the date as is from a string to a date field type. I'm not seeing anything in the data that shows this should be a problem, but upon executing the query i get the following error

"Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

I'm hoping someone sees something I don't

Here's the query

```
Select 
  i.item_no, 
  i.cust_ident_1,
CASE 
  WHEN i.Item_no IS NULL THEN 'Z00000'
    WHEN LEN(i.item_no) <= 4 THEN 'Z00000'
    ELSE LEFT(i.item_no, LEN(i.item_no) - 4) 
  END AS ItemNo,     
 cast(replace(qty_ordered, ',' , '') as integer) as 
W_QtyOrdered,    
 cast(replace(fg_qty, ',' , '') as integer) as 
WFinishedGoodsQty,   
 cast(replace(i.qty_shipped, ',' , '') as integer) as 
WQty_Shipped,    
 cast(replace(i.on_hand_1, ',' , '') as integer) as WOnHand,     
convert(date, due_date) as due_date
from data.email i 
where i._modified >= (select max(_modified) from data.email)
```

Here's a list of dates I'm trying to convert, as they are represented in the csv imported table

```
4/24/19
4/30/19
5/14/19
4/16/19
```

Not sure what I need to do to these days for the conversion to work

Comment: Try DATEFORMAT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I suspect you have bogus data.  Use try_convert().  It will return a NULL if the conversion fails rather than throwing an error.  Example  Select try_convert(date,'4/24/19')